# Change row color base on time

Tags: php

hello anyone can help me. I have a wheelchair loan system. how do I make a date lender row to change color based on time. For example if the loan time of more than 12 hours row will change the yellow, if the loan time over 14 hours row will change the blue color and if the loan time over 24 hours the color row will turn red.
here is the code:

```
<td><div align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-[enter image description here][1]serif" >
        <strong>
<?php 
    $startdateTime = new DateTime($row['tarikh_pinjam']);
    $start=date_format($startdateTime, 'j-n-Y H:i:s'); echo $start;
?>
```

Comment: make three css classes and assign them on td by checking time

Comment: Ooh, it's 2018.  Don't use the font element.  Ever.  Use CSS classes and semantic tags.

Answer (score 0):

I might approach this on the front end with Javascript for dynamic updating after the page has loaded, but the concept is the same.  Basically, use CSS classes.  Something like:

```
<?php
$now = time();   # time in Unix seconds.  Look up what "Unix seconds" are, and the Epoch

foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
    $borrowedAt = some_function_to_convert_to_unix_seconds( $row['tarikh_pinjam'] );
    if ( $now - $borrowedAt > 10800 )
        $cssClass = "threeHoursAgo";
    else if ( $now - $borrowedAt > 7200 )
        $cssClass = "twoHoursAgo";
    else if ( $now - $borrowedAt > 3600 )
        $cssClass = "hourAgo";
?>
<td class="<?= $cssClass; ?>">
    ...
```

I don't know what format your `$row['tarikh_pinjam']` is, but I'll assume you will convert it Unix seconds.  Hence, the `some_function_to_convert_to_unix_seconds` reference to a function that you may need to write.